# Are Cordova Chrome App (CCA) Plugins compatible with Cordova Ionic apps

Tags: cordova, tcp, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-chrome-app

I have an ionic app that needs to make a TCP socket connection between it and a Wifi access point(no internet just a local access point).

The only library I could find for doing this from the client side was [Chrome Sockets](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket)(Deprecated) and [Chrome Sockets TCP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp). Both available as Cordova plugins.

I was able to create the TCP socket, connect, send and receive with the deprecated version. But I always got the same string back in the response that I sent over the connection which was not the expected behavior.

When I moved to the supported Chrome Sockets TCP lib I could create the socket but not connect to it. I came across this [CCA command line tool tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/chrome_apps_on_mobile) after seeing some Stack Overflow posts talking about a `manifest.mobile.json` file which I did not have in my ionic app.

I installed the CCA command line tool and ran through the tutorial to create a basic CCA app. I grabbed the generated `manifest.mobile.json` file from that and through it in the `www` folder of mine and tried to connect again with no better results. Here is the generated `manifest.mobile.json` file with a few lines I added based on ;

```
 {
  "packageId": "com.your.company.ChromeApp",
  // Android-only overrides here (e.g. icons, name, version)
  "android": {
  },
  // iOS-only overrides here (e.g. icons, name, version)
  "ios": {
  },
  // Uncomment to use system WebView rather than Crosswalk
   "webview": "system",

  // Uncomment to enable use of eval()
   "cspUnsafeEval": true,

  // Uncomment to enable use of inline <script>
   "cspUnsafeInline": true,

   "sockets": {
      "tcp": {"connect" : "*"}
   }
}
```

And this is the code used to make and connect to the tcp socket

```
 chrome.sockets.tcp.create(function(createInfo) {
            chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(createInfo.socketId, 'MY_IP', MY_PORT, function(result) {
              if (result === 0) {
                chrome.sockets.tcp.send(createInfo.socketId, PID, function(result) {
                  if (result.resultCode === 0) {
                    console.log('connectAndSend: success');
                    chrome.sockets.tcp.disconnect(createInfo.socketId);
                    chrome.sockets.tcp.close(createInfo.socketId);
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          });
```

And the error message I get

```
failed to connect to /MY_IP (port MY_PORT): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
callbackWithError @ errors.js:30
fail @ sockets.tcp.js:68
cordova.callbackFromNative @ cordova.js:293
processMessage @ cordova.js:1079
processMessages @ cordova.js:1102
```

Comment: why don't you link the plugins instead of linking the libraries?

Comment: The Github repos for the plugins link back to these for the docs anyway. But if it helps here is [chrome-app-socket-tcp plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp) and deprecated [chrome-app-socket plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket)